# Angular Failes to create app

Tags: angular, ubuntu, linux-mint

Command

```
ng new my-app

Error Message
Error: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

OS
Linux Mint 18.2

Installed nodejs

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Installed Angular

```
npm install --unsafe-perm -g @angular/cli
```

Had to use *--unsafe-perm* or got another error when installing angular

Anyone else run into this?  Know how to fix?

Thanks,
Glen

Comment: Please try to format you answer to make it better readable.

Comment: This issue is the same like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217313/angular-cli-ng-new-error/48217502#48217502