# Angular CLI ng new error

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I've installed node from https://nodejs.org/en/download and then I installed angular CLI via NPM using

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

After it's done, I then try to create a new angular project

```
ng new new-project
```

And I get the following error

```
Error: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected.
  You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected.
  You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

I've tried installing the cli using sudo (and without) and I've reinstalled node: I always get the same error.

I can't find anything about anyone having this issue.

I'm using MacOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I follow the steps

- Update Node, npm latest version
- Remove angular-cli 1.6.3
- Install angular-cli 1.5

I could create application, component and others

updated 12-JAN

I update angular-cli up 1.6.4, Node up 9.4.0 and worked fine for me to create new project

Answer (score 6):

Try to use an older version of Angular CLI until this problem get solved.

You can follow this issue in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9172.

EDIT: I found a solution, run these commands:

```
npm un -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been fixed.

Remove `node_modules` and run `npm install` to get the latest dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed issue on:

Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 6.10.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 6.10.3
OS: linux x64

Angular CLI: 1.6.4
Node: 8.0.0
OS: win32 x64

In each cases i'm using nvm.

Works after uninstalling and specifically installing angular cli version 1.5.5

Answer (score 0):

Follow this issues in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9187

Install in your project

```
npm install @angular-devkit/schematics
```

ng -v

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 9.2.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.0
```