# Error: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to generate a component called "hero" using "ng generate component hero" in the cmd line and am getting the following message:

> Error: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
>   You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

[image]
*Note: The error was still occurring before the version warning was a problem*

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular CLI ng new error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217313/angular-cli-ng-new-error)

Answer (score 1):

for an hour was solving the same, eventually concluded:

1. My global and local CLI mismatched (1.6.4 g vs 1.6.3 l),
so I ran `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`

2. After that that was another warning:
 "Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.
More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.", 

so `ng g c my-component --skip-import` now works as expected.
I hope it will help.