# "ng generate module/component" doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript, npm

I get the following error with "ng g c course":

> Error: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can 
>      provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
>      You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an 
>      Observable, Promise,
>      Array, or Iterable.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218027/error-you-provided-an-invalid-object-where-a-stream-was-expected-you-can-provi   and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217313/angular-cli-ng-new-error

Comment: i updated angular-cli to 1.6.4, now it works well